# What circuit breaker to use to protect a SPD under 18th edition?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, surge-suppression

I am installing a Hager SPN180N to protect my residential circuit. I understand that under 18th edition I am required to protect the SPD with a circuit breaker. I want to supply my electrician with the correct kit. It looks like a Type A RCBO is the preferred way to protect a SPD? Can I please ask what circuit breaker(s) (preferably with Hager model numbers) I need to buy to put in series in front of this SPD to protect it against a over current appropriate for this SPD’s over current rating? The instructions manual attached here specifies the spec of the SPD but does not specify how to protect it against over current.

[image]

Comment: Why an RCBO and not an MCB?

Comment: Wouldn't you expect your electrician to provide the proper parts to complete the installation? It's not like you take your own eggs & bread to a restaurant with you when you go out for breakfast...

Answer (score 2):

Surge protection devices like this do not require protection in form of separate breakers. They *are* the protection. Putting a breaker in series will simply disconnect them from circuit at first sign of trouble. Their whole role is to clamp the overvoltage to the ground, even if it ends "killing" them in the process. A brave little devices they are!

Your house/flat already has a main breakers that will blow if the shunted current is large enough. You can ask the electrician to inspect the wires to them.
It is important the device has a good thick ground connection (in that case I would install two units to protect both Phase and Neutral), but if your residence has only 2 wire supply (Phase and Neutral), it goes between them.

I also recommend that you still regular surge suppressor strips for you electronic devices. The device you install only lowers the surge to around 1000Volts and may not be enough to make it harmless for more sensitive devices. The surge suppresor will smooth that down to more safe levels while not burning out so quickly. The devices work in tandem.

Comment: Uhm.. if the three connections are phase, other phase, and ground two devices may not be needed. If it's hot, neutral and ground it only protects the phase whose hot it's attached to

Comment: @keshlam i deleted my previous comment. Jup, that device is only to protect the neutral. Apparently its the wrong one. The Hager UK site doesn't even list it. Perhaps the VME01SPD would be the better choice..

Comment: There _are_ surge suppressors available built into breakers, in some panel  brands, for convenient install. Surprisingly, the one I got attached the suppressor in the protected side of the breaker rather than the buss side. I am guessing this was done because if an MOV does fail after a surge,  it can fail shorted, and they figured they'd let a single breaker blow to handle that rather than having the main blow so you lose power on all circuits. But that's only a guess

Comment: Brave little SPD, indeed! _I think I can, I think I can, I think I can!_

Comment: @keshlam Please notice this is an EU style device, so we are not dealing with two hots and neutral US-style, but rather with one hot (called Phase, L) and either one ProtectiveEarth+Neutral wire or separate Neutral and Ground wires. In case the installation has only two wires, the device goes between them. In case of three wire installation (from mains side), it is recommended to install two, one between phase and ground and one between neutral and ground.  In case you have two hots and neutral, and you are in europe, call electrician now.

Comment: Apologies,; I did miss the fact that it was non-US. Need to thin that one through.

Comment: @Martin you are correct. After contacting Hager support I found out that this is a Neutral protection Type 1+2 surge protector for the Neutral pole. In this case, for a 400v board. For a residential property I should have been looking at the VME01SPD - which as the Hager support verified, does not need a breaker in series - as it has "build in protection". https://hager.com/uk/products/h/vme01spd-cu-surge-protection-kit-type-12